# Roof rack newbie question regarding safety of transporting a desk

Tags: nissan, x-trail

I have a Nissan X-trail with roof rails, looks like this:

[image: x-trail]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](https://d1qrsrfok4yvrh.cloudfront.net/eyJlZGl0cyI6eyJyZXNpemUiOnsid2lkdGgiOjUzNiwiZml0IjoiY292ZXIifX0sImJ1Y2tldCI6InMzLmljcy1hc3NldHMuY28udWsiLCJrZXkiOiJtZWRpYVwvaW1nXC9jYXJfZ2FsbGVyeV9pbWFnZXNcL0U5M2lqZEd0UUJWUDJMVTNIbnJILkpQRyJ9))</sub>

I need to transport 2 of these:

https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/melltorp-table-top-white-90280096/

I really worry this is a silly question, but I've never used the roof before - is there anything to worry about with regards to transporting these on the roof?

My absolute fear is them coming loose and hitting the car behind me.  Assume they're strapped down super tight with ratchet straps (unless there's a better way) - should the nature of these desks -i.e. super flat, cause worry, about how the wind will interact with it?

Is there any top speed I should have in mind - would highway driving be problematic?

Much appreciated for any guidance.

Comment: Are they just the standard rails that run from front to back, with no side to side rails between them?

Comment: It would be useful if you added a photo of the car roof.

Comment: Check the car owners manual about how much weight you can have on the roof - it varies 50kg, 75kg etc

Comment: Thanks - weight wise is ok - my worry is around if there's a max speed, to do with how the air will want to be lifting the flat surface of a desk.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a maintenance or repair question, but about driving technique, which includes loading vehicles. I'd suggest looking at best practice guides to do this properly.

Comment: fair enough. Do you know if there is an other stackexchange for this? This is the closest I could find.

Comment: With just those rails, I can’t see how you can stop it sliding backward or forward. What is your plan?

Comment: @GdD Are questions on how to use features of a vehicle off topic?

Comment: Both the roof and the racks present a curved (convex) surface, not a flat one. Whatever you might try to carry will teeter back-and-forth, and not sit solidly without movement. Using these to carry and large, flat-surface objects is not a good idea.

Comment: The link indicates that they are   table tops, approximately 50 inches by 30 inches, **they will not fit in your car with the back seats folded down?**

Answer (score 2):

In order to transport goods, you should not place the load directly on these rails. Instead, you should fit roof bars across the rails to give support and a straight mounting plane.

Companies like Thule, Halfords and others make bars to fit the X-Trail. The good thing is these bars are suitable to use on most types of car with only the feet and clamps needing changed. My Thule bars have so far come with me across 6 cars - I do have an extensive collection of clamps in the garage now... :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's safe to place two of those tables on the rack. One maybe upside down and tie it down tight, but I don't know about two. I would ask someone with a truck to help you transport them